# Does any one know how can I implement Google authentication with graphql and nestjs

Tags: graphql, nestjs, google-oauth, passport.js

I want to implement Google Authentication using graphql and nestjs.

I have look out for documentation which help me to implement,But not able to find out.Do you have any idea or you can suggest some documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't. Use REST endpoints when integrating with OAuth providers for authentication. Let the rest of your application be in GraphQL if you want, but the `callback` that Google and most other providers hand back will not be in gql format so you'd have to use a middleware to parse it and re-define it, or just use a regular REST endpoint for OAuth